# How to move a csv column

Tags: replace

Suppose a classic csv like this (each number represents an alphanumeric sequence) :

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I was trying to move the 6th column of each line to the beginning of the line using a simple and elegant one liner.

Is there a way to achieve this using something like :

```
g/,/norm 5n<?>d0P
```

I don't know what to put in place of <?> to select the word right after the 5th comma

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you, you guys are the best :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it with `:normal!` command alone:

```
:%normal! 05f,dF,0Pm`0x``P
```

Which executes normal commands for all lines (`%`) one by one:

- `0` to go to beginning of the line
- `5f,` to go to 5th comma
- `dF,` to cut back till comma
- `0` to the beginning
- `P` to Paste before current char
- `` m` ``  to mark end of pasted text
- `0` to go to beginning of the line where now there is a comma
- `x` to cut a comma
- ``` `` ``` to go to the end of the pasted text we marked earlier
- `P` to paste a comma

Note, it wouldn't work for a well formed csv with "fields that have, commas".

There are probably better ways to do it too :)

PS, you can replicate normal command just typing it on the csv line ``` 05f,dF,0Pm`0x``P ```

PPS, tested with:

```
1,2,3,4,5sdf skljsf,6,7
1,2,3,4,5 sdkj lskdj ,6,7
1,2,3,4,5 aksldjfl sjdf ,6,7
```

result:

```
5sdf skljsf,1,2,3,4,6,7
5 sdkj lskdj ,1,2,3,4,6,7
5 aksldjfl sjdf ,1,2,3,4,6,7
```

Comment: Thank you ! i didn't know about the "normal!" syntax nor the mark command, it makes total sens, this is awesome

Comment: Another way you can apply this to multiple lines is to record the command in a macro that ends with `j` or `j0` and then execute the macro N times. The `:%` in Maxim Kim's answer applies the normal command to all lines, but in some cases you may not want all lines.

Comment: @nullromo, if you don't need all lines, visually select whatever you want and do the same `normal` command. Or do `:g/pattern/normal ...`. But yes, macro is another option.